# How to write generic function processing two Lists holding any kind of objects?

Tags: c#

I want to write a function that processs two Lists of the same objects. The function does always the same thing:

1. Find the objects that are only in List2 but not in List1 -> Do something with them
2. Find the object that are in both Lists -> Do something different with them.

Now the point is, that I have List pairs holding different kind of objects to which I want to apply this exact process. 
Example:

```
List<Foo1> L11, L12;
List<Foo2> L21, L22;
List<Foo3> L31, L32;
```

So how do I have to write the code, so that I do not have to repeat the code for each List type ?

Greetings and Thank you

Comment: An equality comparer will [allow to you to tell which items are in each list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx). As for the rest there isn't enough detail to answer. Do you do the same "something" to each type, or a different "something"? If you post the code you have tried to use to solve this it will help.

Comment: This depends a great deal on "something" in "do something with them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prepare a method, like below:

```
static void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2, Action<T> onlyIn2, Action<T> inBoth)
{
    var hash = new HashSet<T>(list1);
    foreach (var item2 in list2)
        if (hash.Contains(item2))
            inBoth(item2);
        else
            onlyIn2(item2);
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
var list1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var list2 = new List<int> {3, 4, 5, 6};
Process(list1, list2, a =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} only in 2", a);
}, a =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} in both", a);
});
```

Note that it uses standard comparison rules (for objects reference equality unless `Equals` is overrided or `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` is implemented).

Comment: So this means instead of defining an EqualityCompare as described by Groo I can just override the Equals Function in my class? Second: I do not exactly understand (though it looks exactly as what I need) the concept of the Actions. So I give the function (Actions) as argument to the function Process? May you please elaborate on that.

Comment: Are these Lambda Expressions?

Comment: Yes, these are lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ already provides two methods which do this:

```
// get all members of L11 not present in L12
var except = L11.Except(L12).ToList();

// get members present in both lists
var intersect = L11.Intersect(L12).ToList();
```

These overloads will use the default comparer for the list element type, so since you want to compare custom classes, you will need to use the overload which accepts a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
var comparer = new CustomComparer();
var except = L11.Except(L12, comparer).ToList();
var intersect = L11.Intersect(L12, comparer).ToList();
```

which you need to write yourself:

```
class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y)
    {
        // return true if equal
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj)
    {
        // return a hash code for boj
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can use the [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx)/[Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) Linq methods as follows:

```
void Process<T>(IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null) {
    //Find the objects that are only in List2 but not in List1 
    foreach(var item in list2.Except(list1, comparer)) {
        // -> Do something with them
    }
    //Find the object that are in both Lists -> Do something different with them.
    foreach(var item in list1.Intersect(list2, comparer)) {
        // -> Do something different with them.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null, what does that mean?

Comment: this means that you can either pass the specific converter to this method or [ignore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx#Anchor_2) this parameter(for example when primitive types used)